# In Java, what does object.class do?

Tags: java, generics

I'm working with Google GSON, and in the docs they [mention](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples) they following:

> ```
> Object Examples
>
> class BagOfPrimitives {
>   private int value1 = 1;
>   private String value2 = "abc";
>   private transient int value3 = 3;
>   BagOfPrimitives() {
>     // no-args constructor
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> (Serialization)
>
> ```
> BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
> Gson gson = new Gson();
> String json = gson.toJson(obj);  
> ==> json is {"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}
> ```
>
> Note that you can not serialize objects with circular references since that will result in infinite recursion.
>
> (Deserialization)
>
> ```
> BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);   
> ==> obj2 is just like obj
> ```

At the very bottom, they use `BagOfPrimitives.class`. What does that do exactly? (I would imagine it might return the class, but in that case I'd expect the code just to omit the '.class').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a *class literal* - it gives a reference to the `Class` object representing the particular class. See [section 15.8.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) for more details. For example:

```
String text = "Hello";
Class<?> classFromObject = text.getClass();
Class<?> classFromLiteral = String.class;
System.out.println(classFromObject == classFromLiteral); // true
```

In the case of the deserialization, it's to tell the deserializer what type to use to try to deserialize the data as.

Answer (score 0):

You put a type in the method so you don't have to cast it. The `fromJson` method is generic and resolves the type itself according to the type you write in there...

```
<T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT)
```